# column subsets and indexes in R in modifying a data frame

Tags: r

For the dataset in R, mtcars, I am trying to make a subset of the data frame, from column 1, 2, and 8 and 9. I want to index columns 8 and 9 so i can call upon one or the other in my function in order to get a certain output.

so I did

```
highestmpg <- function(cyl, type) {

  type <- mtcars[, c(8, 9)]
  df <- mtcars[, c(1, 2, type)]
```

I got an error this far into the function

> Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

I don't understand this error, can someone help me figure out how to circumvent this error?

My purpose is to make a data frame in which I can later input column 2 (cyl), either column 8 or 9 value (0 or 1), in order to get a value for column 1 (mpg)

I want to rank mtcars by cyl, then by type, in order to end up with an organized data frame for mpg, in order to later find the highest mpg, depending on the input

```
ranking <- mtcars[order(cyl, type, mpg)]
```

I apologize in advance, I am still a beginner in R, and I might not be correct in all the terminology and I would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

If I execute the code you have given I don't get the error that you report, but a different one. I will assume you missed a parenthesis when you type the second line so it should read:

```
type <- mtcars[, c(8, 9)]
df <- mtcars[, c(1, 2, type)]
```

The error message says that you are trying to subset with a list. This is due to `type` being a `data.frame` (which is actually a list in R) so you prepend the list items 1 and 2 to this list and get the result:

```
> c(1, 2, type)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

$vs
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1

$am
 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

It is not meaningful to use this for subsetting, and you probably didn't intend to. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, so this is the only help I can offer for now.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're passing a data.frame `type` to a function (`c`) that expects a list of a single type. This

```
mtcars[, c(1, 2, 8)]
```

or this

```
mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "am")]
```

will work.

It's also unclear if you need a function here. This should give you what you want (ranking of cars by cyl and either vs or am)

```
mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs), ]
mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am), ]
```